# VBA - Get cursor position as cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which works fine for retrieving the cursor position as pixels:

```
Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
' Create custom variable that holds two integers
Type POINTAPI
    Xcoord As Long
    Ycoord As Long
End Type

Sub GetCursorPosDemo()
    Dim llCoord As POINTAPI
    ' Get the cursor positions
    GetCursorPos llCoord
    ' Display the cursor position coordinates
    MsgBox "X Position: " & llCoord.Xcoord & vbNewLine & "Y Position: " & llCoord.Ycoord
End Sub
```

I'd like it to return the cell address on which my cursor currently is, or perhaps the coordinates in Points, so I can convert it to an address. Is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint` to get the cell address.

---

```
Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
' Create custom variable that holds two integers
Type POINTAPI
    Xcoord As Long
    Ycoord As Long
End Type

Sub GetCursorPosDemo()
    Dim llCoord As POINTAPI
    Dim rng As Range
    ' Get the cursor positions
    GetCursorPos llCoord
    ' Display the cursor position coordinates
    'MsgBox "X Position: " & llCoord.Xcoord & vbNewLine & "Y Position: " & llCoord.Ycoord

    Set rng = GetRange(llCoord.Xcoord, llCoord.Ycoord)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell under mouse is :" & rng.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "Not a valid location."
    End If

End Sub

Function GetRange(x As Long, y As Long) As Range
    Set GetRange = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(x, y)
End Function
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: If I have a bunch of merged cells, is there a workaround for it to show only the "mother" cell? Because it is showing different results based on the place the mouse is located.

Comment: use `rng.MergeArea.cells(1,1).Address `

Comment: Is there a workaround if the cells are overlayed by a picture?

Comment: Achieved it by hiding the shapes before the code execution and showing them right after