# Display MsgBox on cell click - even when the cell is already selected

Tags: vba, excel, events, onclick

I want a `MsgBox` to appear when cell `A1` is clicked. I want it to appear even if `A1` is already active when it is clicked:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
    MsgBox ("message")
  End If

  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This code works only if cell `A1` is not already selected when I click on it.  Currently the message box does not appear in this case.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Would double-click instead of click work for you?

Comment: *"I want it to appear even if that cell is already active and is being clicked on"* This won't work because the event is called `SelectionChange` which means the selection must change to trigger the event.

Comment: @ashleedawg It's better than nothing, even though the one-click is preferable

Comment: Why not just use a button?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29758475/2165759) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47271141/2165759).

Comment: @Ans - note that in your code example, the two lines enabling & disabling events (with `Application.EnableEvents`) will have no effect and are unnecessary.  This would only be needed if the code within the event will/might trigger *another* event.

Comment: @Josh Eller What do you mean by that? Place a button with "A1 info" text near cell A1 or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is using `Worksheet_SelectionChange` which only fires when a different cell is selected (hence the name `Selection Change`).

Alternatively, if it's okay if your [unknown] goal is attained using **double click** or **right click** then there are other worksheet events that will help:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox Target.Address & " was double clicked"
    Cancel = True 'don't edit cell
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox Target.Address & " was right clicked"
    Cancel = True 'don't open context menu
End Sub
```

Note that the code for these event procedures need to be [placed in the worksheet module](https://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html#Worksheet).

---

### Edit: *More creative ways*

**Click Event via `PeekMessage` API**

- If it must be a single click, there are "sneakier" ways to accomplish this, such as adding a **Click event**.  This is not a built-in feature of Excel VBA, and thus, this method is not generally recommended.

  It involves checking for the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message when a cell is mouse-clicked, which is accomplished by calling the [`PeekMessage` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx) inside the [`Worksheet_SelectionChange` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.SelectionChange).  More info and examples [**here**](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/208072-mouse-click-event-post1017303.html#post1017303).

**Transparent command button**

- There could also be a round-about way to accomplish this using an [**ActiveX Command Button**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50144020/8112776) with no caption, with the `BackStyle` property set to `frmBackStyleTransparent`.

  [image]

Neither of these methods have been tested and you might need to do some fancy coding to get them to work. Depending on *how often* the same cell will be clicked that is already selected (and therefore how that functionality is to you), you may want to simply re-think the layout of your worksheet.

For example, you could **add an extra column** and have the user click the cell *next to* the one with the value to activate your message box.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Worksheet.BeforeDoubleClick` Event** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.beforedoubleclick)
- MSDN : [**`Worksheet.BeforeRightClick` Event** (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.BeforeRightClick)
- Chip Pearson : [**Events in Excel VBA**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)