# How do I return the address of the currently selected cell and update it as the cursor moves?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a grid referencing the first two positions of an alphanumeric string, where each position can be A-Z or 0-9 (with a few letters excluded). The two axes are in column B and row 2 to permit more descriptive headers.

To aid in keeping track of where I am, I'd like the sheet to show in a separate cell the two-character reference for the currently selected cell.

[image: VIN table showing current cell display example.]

I've had a few ideas, but it's been three years since I did much VBA and my memory is failing me. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Use `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)` or alternatively `Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target as Range)` depending on when you want this updated. Then using `Target.Column` and `Target.Row` you can return the required string. Additionally you can use the `CELL("Address")` method to write a front end formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("AK3").Value = Cells(Target.Row, 2) & Cells(2, Target.Column)
End Sub
```

and get rid of the merged cells ;-)

Comment: This does not use the cursor's position as requested by OP

Comment: OP stated : " the cell currently containing the cursor." and his own made up grid in 2nd row and 2nd column. (so not the cell where the Mouse-Cursor is)

Comment: I see, fair point about the actual reference (self-made table instead of excel's). Still, your method refers to the selected cell, and not the cursor's position

Comment: OP wants his coordinates of the ActiveCell (Which I read as Cell containing the cursor)

Comment: *"cell currently containing the cursor"* <> ActiveCell, as the cursor can be positioned on a wildly different cell than whichever cell is active

Comment: Actually, re-reading the question, both options might be possible. +1 for both approuches, will have to see what OP had in mind :)

Comment: @JvdV please explain, I can't see how ActivCell can mean cursor pos

Comment: @TimStack, there are two types of cursors, I also am lead to believe OP means the Mousecursor, or rather mousepointer, but it could be possible OP means the textcursor, or rather the caret, which would indicate the active cell.

Comment: @JvdV ah, gotcha

Comment: Yes - the question refers to the caret rather than the mouse pointer. I'll clarify that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea!

Based on [this answer on a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47271553/10540017), you could check the cursor's location every x seconds. That way you won't have to manually execute the macro, and the cursor location will be updated automatically:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
' Create custom variable that holds two integers
Type POINTAPI
    Xcoord As Long
    Ycoord As Long
End Type

Sub GetCursorPosDemo()
    Dim llCoord As POINTAPI
    Dim rng As Range, destrng As Range

    ' Get the cursor positions
    GetCursorPos llCoord

    Set rng = GetRange(llCoord.Xcoord, llCoord.Ycoord)
    Set destrng = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AK3") 'destination of cursor reference

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        destrng.Value = rng.Address
    Else
        destrng.Value = "N/A"
    End If

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Module1.GetCursorPosDemo" 'in case you place the sub in Module1
End Sub

Function GetRange(x As Long, y As Long) As Range
    Set GetRange = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(x, y)
End Function
```

---

**EDIT**
As you request the cell reference to be in accordance with your self-made table:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
' Create custom variable that holds two integers
Type POINTAPI
    Xcoord As Long
    Ycoord As Long
End Type

Sub GetCursorPosDemo()
    Dim llCoord As POINTAPI
    Dim destrng As Range

    ' Get the cursor positions
    GetCursorPos llCoord

    Set destrng = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AK3") 'destination of cursor reference

    destrng.Value = GetRange(llCoord.Xcoord, llCoord.Ycoord)

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Module1.GetCursorPosDemo" 'in case you place the sub in Module1
End Sub

Function GetRange(x As Long, y As Long) As String
    Dim ActualRange As Range
    Set ActualRange = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(x, y)

    If ActualRange.Column > 2 And ActualRange.Row > 2 Then
        GetRange = ActiveWindow.Cells(ActualRange.Row, "B") & ActiveWindow.Cells(2, ActualRange.Column)
    Else
        GetRange = "N/A"
    End If    
End Function
```

---

As this method uses `Application.OnTime`, and thus no `Do...Loop`, other methods can run at the same time as this code. The code above gets put at a halt while the other method runs. With a loop, no other code can run.

Comment: Indeed a more useful approach!